# Unable to output created custom object from function

Tags: powershell-4.0

when calling the function below, it doesn't display output on "Windows PowerShell console" but on "Windows Powershell ISE" can.

```
Function DNSSearchOrders{
    $Computer = $env:computername
    $Networks = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter IPEnabled=TRUE -ComputerName $Computer
    $DNSServers = $Networks.DNSServerSearchOrder
    $NetworkName = $Networks.Description
    $PrimaryDNSServer = $DNSServers[0]
    $SecondaryDNSServer = $DNSServers[1]
    $TertiaryDNSServer = $DNSServers[2]

    $OutputObj = @()

    $NewObj = New-Object -Type PSObject
    $NewObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Domain -Value $Computer.ToUpper()
    $NewObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name PrimaryDNSServers -Value $PrimaryDNSServer
    $NewObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SecondaryDNSServers -Value $SecondaryDNSServer
    $NewObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TertiaryDNSServers -Value $TertiaryDNSServer
    $OutputObj += $NewObj

    $NewObj = New-Object -Type PSObject
    $NewObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Domain -Value contoso.com
    $NewObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name PrimaryDNSServers -Value 111.111.88.88
    $NewObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SecondaryDNSServers -Value 222.333.444.88
    $NewObj| Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TertiaryDNSServers -Value "DC IP Address"
    $OutputObj += $NewObj

    $OutputObj
}

DNSSearchOrders
```